# JHipster how to change the view from an entity to Pageable

Tags: java, pagination, jhipster, jdl

I am looking for the easiest way for including Pagination for one of the entities I have created with the help of JDL Studio which JHipster provides. I have not chosen the Pagination option in the jdl file as I do not need Pagination in general, only for one entity. How can I make this change manually?

Comment: I don't get your point, in JDL you can enable pagination per entity http://www.jhipster.tech/jdl/

Comment: Ok yes you are right. So you suggest I import the jdl file again into my project ? Can I only include this one entity (this time with Pagination) in the jdl file to make this change happen?

Answer (score 1):

The below JDL shows how you can specify pagination for one entity.  Entity A will be the only entity with pagination

```
entity A {
    name String required
}

entity B {}

entity C {}

paginate A with pagination
```

For more information on declaring options in JDL, see [the official docs](http://www.jhipster.tech/jdl/#optiondeclaration).

Comment: Hi Jon, one reason I tend to use entity generator through questions over JDL is that I don't know how to make incremental changes like here only one one entity in JDL without regenerating all entities. Our doc does not cover this unless I'm wrong.

Comment: This behavior changed recently.  It used to be that on import of JDL, all entities would regenerate.  Now, only entities that have changes are regenerated.  Commit: https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/commit/f3b731fcb3ddee74b54375b3c552c7849693c02d

Answer (score 1):

Following are the steps to add pagination to the existing entity which does not have existing pagination.

1. Change `"pagination"` option
   You can do this by changing by `"pagination": "no"` to `"pagination": true` from `EntityName.json` file from `./ProjectName/.jhipster` directory.
2. Update JDL file xxx.jh

> ```
> entity Company{
>     name String
> }
>
> entity Employee{
>     empName String
> }
>
> paginate Employee with pagination
> ```

I want pagination for Employees only so I have updated `paginate Employee with pagination`
3. Import entities by using,
`jhipster import-jdl xxx.jh`

After successful import, the impact will be on both the server and client side.
On the server side mainly `EntityNameResource.java` and `EntityNameService.java` will change.
On the client side EntityName.component.html, multiple supporting.ts files will change.

Answer (score 0):

1- go to:

```
/{projectRoot}/.jhipster/YourEntity.json
```

2- Find And set pagination property like this:

From

```
"pagination": "no",
```

To

```
"pagination": "pagination",
```

3- open a prompt and type:

```
jhipster entity [entityName]
```

This ask you to reload your entity you can choose "regerate" or "update" (and more options) for your entity.

This should implement all pagination system.

Tested in Jhipster 6.8.0